# Syntax error when converting Byte to Char in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, char, byte

An error pops up when I write this:

```
ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add(Convert.ToChar(byteData(i)))
```

The error is:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Convert' accepts this number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Convert.ToChar` will work for converting a byte to a char. for example the following cod will work without any problem:

```
    Dim byteArray(10) As Byte
    byteArray(0) = 65 'code of 'A' char
    Dim ch As Char
    ch = Convert.ToChar(byteArray(0)) 'ch becomes 'A'c
```

Can you explai more about what type is `byteData(i)` in your code? maybe it is not a byte as you expected. please check it or give more info from where you have defined it?

Comment: Dim byteData(100) As Byte
            Dim size As Integer = soc.Receive(byteData)
            ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add("rec")
            For i As Integer = 0 To size
 ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Add(Convert.ToChar(byteData(i)))

Comment: and your method is still highlighting the 'Convert' word